# JBPM Console Running Under WildFly, Simple Java Example Crashes

Tags: java, wildfly, jbpm

I've recently deployed the JBPM Console, 6.2.0, within my Wildfly 8.2 container.

The web-based applications seem to work well – WildFly and jbpm-console. I deployed the console using this tutorial: http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2015/03/jbpm-62-installation-and-upgrade-from.html.

I have not yet configured persistence, nor added a datasource, as I'm only attempting to run this simple example first.

I'm running all of this on an virtual 64-Bit Ubuntu server using Java SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_65-b17.

When I run the project as a Junit Test I get the following:

```
org.jbpm.process.builder.ProcessBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newProcessBuilder(Lorg/drools/compiler/compiler/PackageBuilder;)Lorg/drools/compiler/compiler/ProcessBuilder;
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.ProcessBuilderFactory.newProcessBuilder(ProcessBuilderFactory.java:11)
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.createProcessBuilder(PackageBuilder.java:408)
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:346)
        at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:242)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:40)
        at org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.<init>(SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.java:92)
        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.<init>(SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.java:86)
        at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.<init>(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder$Factory.<clinit>(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:41)
        at com.sample.ProcessTest.testProcess(ProcessTest.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

My Java code is here (crashing at `environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()`):

```
package com.sample;

import org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEngine;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironment;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManager;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManagerFactory;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.kie.internal.runtime.manager.context.EmptyContext;
import org.kie.internal.utils.KieHelper;

/**
* This is a sample file to test a process.
*/
public class xx extends JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();

        RuntimeEnvironment environment = null;

        environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
            .newDefaultInMemoryBuilder()
            .addAsset(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("sample.bpmn2"), ResourceType.BPMN2)
            .addEnvironmentEntry("IS_JTA_TRANSACTION", false).get();

        RuntimeManager manager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(environment);

        RuntimeEngine runtime = manager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());

        RuntimeEngine engine  = manager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());

        KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");

        // check whether the process instance has completed successfully
        assertProcessInstanceCompleted(processInstance.getId(), ksession);
        assertNodeTriggered(processInstance.getId(), "Hello");

        manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(engine);
        manager.close();
        ksession.dispose();
    }

}
```

And here's my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hellojbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellojbpm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source />
                    <target />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-audit</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-runtime-manager</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-flow-builder</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-flow</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I have tried different versions of jBPM on different versions of Wildfly, and I ran into endless problems and bugs. I'll abandon my tests and return to Activiti (which is buggy, too, but not quite as).